# Does any one know how to break second page in mpdf?

Tags: mpdf

Does any one know how to break second page in mpdf. i am getting two PDF page but second one is blank so i want to remove that blank page.

{

include_once("mpdf-master/mpdf.php");
include_once('../../../../wp-load.php');

$htm = get_template_directory_uri().'/admin/_invoice.php?id='.$_GET['id'];

$html = file_get_contents("$htm");

$mpdf=new mPDF('c');

$mpdf->debug = true;

$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);

$mpdf->Output();
exit;

?>}

Thanks
Sanket

Comment: Could you add the code of your HTML template?

Comment: It means your HTML content is too long/big for one PDF page.